# Как организовать вид в MVC с поддержкой выбор главного шаблона?

Tags: php, mvc

Добрый день. Столкнулся с реализацией Вида в паттерне MVC. 
Имею вот такой код:
http://pastebin.com/VKddX07T
Но этим способом я смогу вывести только этот блок который я передаю с контроллера. А как мне этот блок вставить в главный шаблон, допустим main?